# From static blogging to manual html editing?

Tags: wordpress, html

I have my site done with WordPress. It's been like that for a few years.

Now, I have started to look for other options. WordPress has all these things I don't really need. One option would be static blogging. Generate the content locally and deploy the generated content to web with rsync, for example. There is tools like Jekyll, Hyde and Octopress for this.

But even Octopress seems like an overkill for me. It really feels like that. I don't need all those plugins it comes with. I'm building an image heavy site for myself, just a place where I can put my drawings that I create with my tablet.

So what if I would just manually edit HTML-files, where every file would become "a post" and make an index for them at root of my site? Come to think of it, I could work faster with this type of solution, even compared to Octopress. I could have a blank "post template" as raw html and set it as fill in snippet in TextExpander. In there, I could fill all the details for that html file like the title tag and so on.

I'm not really a coder. I draw things and write stories. In spite of this, I somehow have managed to work my way around with WordPress and recently, with Octopress.

I'm just thinking why Jekyll or Octopress or Hyde or Cactus would be a better fit for me instead of manually editing html files, and calling them "articles" or "posts"?

Thanks for any views or answers.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to go to static html?

If you have problems with using too many resources, you should add a caching plugin to your WordPress install and that will help greatly.

Comment: I have a caching plugin, and my hosting is at WPEngine, and they have optimized the caching plugin for optimal performance. My concern with them is the hosting pricing, especially allowed views/month, and combined this with not needing all the features WordPress has, I have started to think other options. Because I don't need all the options a dynamic system has to offer and I'm creating an image heavy site, I got interested in static html.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time you still want some "dynamic" functionality that happens every time you add a page. For example you probably want to have a RSS/Atom feed so that people can subscribe to your site. And you want that automatically updated when you add a new page. You probably also want something to generate a sitemap file for the search engines to index it better.
These static site generators are able to do that well, so I would recommend using one.